# Redux toolkit. Uncaught Error: uSES not initialized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mern, redux-toolkit

I'm learning about the **react-redux toolkit** and here is some problem I'm facing I just simply want to **increment** and **decrement** numbers by clicking on buttons.

File no.1(***counterReducer.js***)

```
import {createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
export const counter = createSlice({
    name:'counter',
    initialState:{
        value:0
    },
    reducers:{
        increment:(state)=>{
            state.value += 1
        },
        decrement:(state)=>{
            state.value -= 1
        },
        incrementByAmount:(state,action)=>{
            state.value += action.payload
        }
    }
})
export const { increment, decrement, incrementByAmount} = counter.actions
export default counter.reducer
```

File no.2(***store.js***)

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import counterReducers from "./counterReducers";

export default configureStore({
    reducer:{
        counter: counterReducers
    }
})
```

File no.3(***index.js***)

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux/es/exports';
import store from './state/store';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

File no.4(***Home.js***)

in this file I'm trying to use state.

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux/es/exports";
import { increment } from "../state/counterReducers";
const Home = () => {
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <>
      <li>
        <a href="/" className="px-2 py-1 bg-cyan-500">Your balance:{counter}</a></li>
      <button className="ml-2 m-1 px-3 bg-orange-500"
        onClick={() => {dispatch(increment())}}>+</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

And This is the image of error.
[image: the image of error.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in your `useSelector`, you aren't accessing the state at all, just try to use `state.counter.value` instead of `state.counter`.

```
const Home = () => {

  // change to state.counter.value, so you get the state value
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter.value);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <>
      <li>
        <a href="/" className="px-2 py-1 bg-cyan-500">Your balance:{counter}</a></li>
      <button className="ml-2 m-1 px-3 bg-orange-500"
        onClick={() => {dispatch(increment())}}>+</button>
    </>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

If still, you are getting the same error then re-consider how you are importing `useSelector`

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
```

instead of

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux/es/exports";
```