# Redux toolkit Uncaught Error: uSES not initialized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am using `redux-toolkit` and facing a problem. I am not sure why it is happening and where is the problem. Appreciate any help.

There is exactly the same issue faced by another developer which he got the answer but in my case, the issue lies in some other place I think. [Link to that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72723517/redux-toolkit-uncaught-error-uses-not-initialized)

**The error I am getting**

[image]

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import { Provider } from 'react-redux/es/exports'

import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

import store from './store/state'
import { ProfileContextProvider } from './store/profile-context'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ProfileContextProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ProfileContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
// import './App.css';
import React, { Suspense } from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Layout from './Layout'

import LoadingSpinner from './Components/LoadingSpinner/'

const Login = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Auth/login'))
const Signup = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Auth/signup'))
const Home = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Home'))
const ProductOutlet = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Products/ProductOutlet'))
const Products = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Products'))
const ProductDetail = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/ProductDetail'))
const Cart = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Cart'))
const Profile = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Profile'))
const Orders = React.lazy(() => import('./Pages/Orders'))

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Suspense 
          fallback={
            <LoadingSpinner/>
          }
        >
          <Routes>
            <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
            <Route path='signup' element={<Signup />} />

            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='products' element={<ProductOutlet />} >
              <Route index element={<Products />} />
              <Route path=":productId" element={<ProductDetail />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path='cart' element={<Cart />} />
            <Route path='profile' element={<Profile />} />
            <Route path='orders' element={<Orders />} />
          </Routes>
        </Suspense>
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**src/store/state/index.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

import authSliceReducer from './auth-slice'

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: authSliceReducer
    }
})

export default store
```

**src/store/state/auth-slice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const initialAuthState = {
    token: null,
    isAuthenticated: false
}

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'authentication',
    initialState: initialAuthState,
    reducers: {
        login(state, action) {
            state.token = action.payload.token
            state.isAuthenticated = true
        },

        logout(state) {
            state.token = null
            state.isAuthenticated = false
        }
    }
})

export const authActions = authSlice.actions
export default authSlice.reducer
```

**src/pages/Home/index.js**

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux/es/exports"

import ProfileContext from "../../store/profile-context"

const Home = () => {
    const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isAuthenticated)
    const profileContext = useContext(ProfileContext)

    return (
        <>
            <h3>Welcome to the the store</h3>
            {/* <h4>Is logged in: {isLoggedIn}</h4> */}
            <p>User profile</p>
            <p>{profileContext.email}</p>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies o line number 2 of the file src/Pages/Home/index.js

I am importing the `useSelector` from `react-redux/es/exports` but it should be from `react-redux`

Just replace

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux/es/exports"
```

with

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
```